# What does public protected mean?

Tags: c++-cli

I am trying to create a instance of class but I keep on getting the following error message.

> candidate function(s) not accessible

After going through the definition of the class which I was trying to instantiate, I realised that the constructor is declared as

```
public protected:  Class name (paramters);
```

What does "public protected" together at the same time mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke3a209d.aspx#BKMK_Member_visibility):

> Member is public inside the assembly but protected outside the assembly.